# Double values (products) in Commerce cart form

Tags: 8, commerce, i18n-l10n, domain-access

I use Drupal [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) version `8.x-2.15`. I have a multilingual Drupal site with multiple languages based on domain.

mystic.com -> EN language
mystic.eu -> NL language

etc

I added relationships:

```
(order_items: Order item) Product variation
(Product variation) Product
```

To get the `image_field` available to show a thumbnail in my cart form. This works fine.

After I added those relationships and I add **one** product to my shopping cart and I see now the number of times that I translated my product back in the shopping cart, like:
My product
My product
My product
My product

(so above product is translated into 4 languages).

I've fixed this by adding a filter to the view:

```
Product: Translation language Is one of Content language selected for page
```

It looks like this is working but I see now 2 values (see screenshot)
[image]

It doubled the added product. But the price and quantity shows 1.

Comment: Did you add any contextual filters? You've checked that you're combining variations in the cart?

Comment: @TonyTheFerg I have a contextual filter `Order: ID`. How do I check combining variations in the cart?

Comment: Make sure to check that the product variation is set to Combine order items containing the same product variation.. This is under Manage Displayfor the product-type in question. @ admin/commerce/config/product-types/YOUR-PRODUCT-TYPE/edit/display.

For the Variations field, click the settings icon to the right, and ensure that Combine order items containing the same product variation. is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `commerce_cart _form` view under **Advanced**, edit the **Query Settings**, and set it to `DISTINCT`.

Comment: This is already set in Manage Display...

Comment: Is your contextual filter default as it came?

Comment: Also have you tested removing relationship requirements? (not the relationship itself, but the requirement of it)

Comment: I am not sure. It's set to Provide default value type Fixed

Comment: ok. that should be fine then

Comment: Try requiring relationships for the new relationships you added.

Comment: For all three relationships I have unset Require this relationship. But it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Last guess, try to remove the filter criteria, and set the contextual filter to the language selected. You might want to first save changes and export your config, so that you can import config to revert your changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101614/discussion-between-meez-and-tonytheferg).

Comment: Answer edited. Please review

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same situation and in my case the solution was to filter the products on the current language or neutral / not applicable language.

The duplicate result was a translation of that related product. Afterwards the "DISTINCT" option could be removed.

So try filtering on current language and language neutral / not applicable.